# Does a new node.js process created by fork (new process) or spawn (child process) get it's own separate call stack?

Tags: node.js, fork, callstack, spawn

When creating a new node.js process programmatically  by forking a process or spawning a new child process; does the new process or child process get it's own separate call stack?

Answer (score 1):

Yes because as you mention yourself, they are new processes.

From wikipedia:

> - processes are typically independent, while threads exist as subsets of a process
> - processes carry considerable state information, whereas multiple threads within a process share state as well as memory and other resources
> - processes have separate address spaces, whereas threads share their address space

In fact, threads have their own call stack as well so, new node.js processes regardless of how they were created must.