# Node.js master process vs child process

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't find the answer to this question, when a master process spawns a child process, are they completely separate? What I mean is do they share any of the following:
 - Call stack
 - Event loop
 - Task queue

After watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ I am trying to grasp how node process work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Child processes in node.js work mostly the same as child processes created by `popen`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process). You have handles to the stdin/stdout/stderr and pid. The child process does not share any other resources (see how `fork` and `exec` work for details).

Also: [Does a new node.js process created by fork (new process) or spawn (child process) get it's own separate call stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36937056/does-a-new-node-js-process-created-by-fork-new-process-or-spawn-child-process)

Additionally: [node.js child process - difference between spawn & fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861362/node-js-child-process-difference-between-spawn-fork)